# Reading "real" data type in a SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have a method that pulls down data from a SQL Server Compact db:

```
// Open the same connection with the same connection string.
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(DatabaseControl.conString))
{
   con.Open();
   // Read specific values in the table.
   using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Result FROM CpuResults WHERE Date = @date", con))
   {
      List<float> results = new List<float>();
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", Form1.date);
      SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

      while (reader.Read())
      {
         float resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
         results.Add(resultsoutput);
      }
```

The "type" for results in the "Result" column on cpuResults is defined as `Real`. I am trying to get this data into a float format as the data within the `Result` column is e.g. 0.02 and 1.23 etc. Although when I run my method I get:

> Specified cast is not valid.

If I change the data type of column `Result` to int, the problem does not happen..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
float resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

You are trying to get an integer and place the value into a `float`.

Either get a `float` to begin with:

```
float resultsoutput = reader.GetFloat(0);
```

Or change the type of variable:

```
int resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this where your cast is failing?

```
float resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

Try this:

```
float resultsoutput = reader.GetFloat(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try reader.GetFloat(0)?